# Get two or more strings in one string

Tags: javascript

I want to get two or more strings in one string for example:

```
var data = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"link":"/main","link":"/old"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"link":"/new"xxxxx';

var index = 'link":"';

data.substring(data.lastIndexOf(index) + index.length,data.lastIndexOf('"')); // i want to get all /main , /old , /new in the var data
```

Result:
`/new`

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do? Can you give an example of what your output should be?

Comment: This looks like you have a JSON do you? I mean those `xxxxxx` are curly braces `{` :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You want to use .split()?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Why would there be braces between `"/old"` and `"link"` ?

Comment: @Andreas You got the idea, don't you?

Comment: Yes, that your assumption doesn't make much sense (as does the example from OP).

Comment: @Andreas OK....

Comment: @YuryTarabanko my point is not getting the values with curly braces in here i want get these strings only /old , /new , /main in this string

Comment: How did you end up with that string value  for `data` ? Maybe there's a problem with that. And by solving that problem maybe your current question can be solved

Comment: @naham3k If you have valid json string you don't need to work with it as a string. It might be (and usually is) easier to use `JSON.parse` and work with javascript objects.

Comment: @naham3k So it would be helpful if you post your actual data instead of `xxxxx` not everyone (khe-khe) can think abstractly enough to understand what you are hiding there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to guess what you want achieve. You could use the following code to get all the links of your string as a array

```js
var data = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"link":"/main","link":"/old"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"link":"/new"xxxxx';

var result = data.match(/\/.+?(?=")/g)
```

The result would be the following:

(3) ["/main", "/old", "/new"]

0: "/main"

1: "/old"

2: "/new"

length: 3